# Query neo4j with Cypher DSL using point.withinBBox()

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spatial, cypher-dsl

I want to find locations in my neo4j database that are within a bounding box. There is a function called point.withinBBox() that I want to use. I build my queries dynamically using Cypher DSL. This is the kind of query I want to run:

```
MATCH (loc:Location)
WHERE point.withinBBox(loc.coordinates, point({longitude: 2.592773, latitude: 46.346928}), point({longitude: 18.654785, latitude: 55.714735}))
RETURN loc
```

In my Java code I dynamically chain conditions like this:

```
conditions = Conditions.noCondition();
conditions = conditions.and(new_condition);
```

So I want to get a `Condition` that encapsulates the point.withinBBox() part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in `Functions` call to do this yet, but you can easily create a custom one via `Cypher.call`. The function returned can be turned into a condition via `.asCondition()` like this:

```java
@Test
void bbBox() {

    Node location = Cypher.node("Location").named("loc");
    Expression sw = Functions.point(Cypher.mapOf("latitude", Cypher.literalOf(46.346928), "longitude", Cypher.literalOf(2.592773)));
    Expression ne = Functions.point(Cypher.mapOf("latitude", Cypher.literalOf(55.714735), "longitude", Cypher.literalOf(18.654785)));
    Expression withinBBox = Cypher.call("point.withinBBox")
        .withArgs(location.property("coordinates"), sw, ne).asFunction();

    Condition conditions = Conditions.noCondition();
    conditions = conditions.and(withinBBox.asCondition());

    String stmt = Cypher.match(location).where(conditions).returning(location).build().getCypher();
    assertThat(stmt).isEqualTo("MATCH (loc:`Location`) WHERE point.withinBBox(loc.coordinates, point({latitude: 46.346928, longitude: 2.592773}), point({latitude: 55.714735, longitude: 18.654785})) RETURN loc");
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I knew about Cypher.call but was missing some other parts, e. g. I did not realize that point() is of course also a function.

Comment: Yes, the function takes in a map and deciding on the keys whether you want a point (cartesian) or an actual coordinate (WGS-84), and you could also specify which SRID.

For convenience I added this with an opinionated approach wrt cartesian / coordinate: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl/commit/2d06a7d41a95643527414b196727508286346bcb